# How can you catch and handle exceptions from the WebView component in C#?

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-store

How can exceptions (such as bubbled up javascript errors) be caught from the `WebView` component in C# that would otherwise crash the app - so I can handle/log them?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are not bubbled up from web pages through the `WebView` component during runtime - only when debugging if just in time compilation is selected for 'script' in the options menu.

To stop the exceptions bubbling up whilst debugging, go tools->options->debugging->Just-in-time and untick 'script'

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/18/nine-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview.aspx#AN10